# Performing logarithmic data transformation for Sentinel-1 using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculate the logarithmic ratio of VV and VH bands of Sentinel-1 images according following equation: log(Ratio) = log(VV) - log(VH). The code is running fine (no error messages), but I don't get any values for the ratio. Unfortunately, I can not find the error. I exported the test image 'LogRatio' and checked in GIS software, also as .csv in Excel, and there are no values at all.

```js
// Filter to get S1-images with VV and VH dual polarization.
var S1_asc = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filterDate(start, finish)
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution', 'H'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10))
    .filterBounds(ROI)
    .select('VV','VH');
print('Collection: S1', S1_asc);

// log VV/VH ratio

// select one image from time series to create function.
var imageS1 = ee.Image(
  S1_asc.filterDate('2017-05-06', '2017-05-07')
    .first()
);

// create function on band math and expression()
var addLogRatio = function(imageS1) {
  var logVV = imageS1.select('VV').log();
  var logVH = imageS1.select('VH').log();
  var logratio = logVV.subtract(logVH).rename('logVV/VH');
  var logratio_float = logratio.toFloat();
  return imageS1.addBands(logratio_float);
};

// Test the addLogRatio function on a single image.
var logratio_float = addLogRatio(imageS1);
print('Test Image: LogRatio', logratio_float);

// Apply addLogRatio function to all image of image.collection.
var S1_asc_logRATIO = S1_asc.map(addLogRatio);
print('Collection: LogRatio', S1_asc_logRATIO);
```

Answer (score 5):

The [COPERNICUS/S1_GRD](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S1_GRD) collection is already log scaled (i.e. `10*log10(x)`) and as a result many of the values are negative. Your script is further taking the natural log of the values using [ee.Image.log()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagelog), and because the natural log of a negative number is not defined, the result is masked out.

This can be corrected as follows:

```js
var addLogRatio = function(img) {
  var logVV = img.select('VV');
  var logVH = img.select('VH');
  var logratio = logVV.subtract(logVH).rename('logVV/VH');
  var logratio_float = logratio.toFloat();
  return img.addBands(logratio_float);
};
```

Which results in non-masked values that can be displayed on the interactive map:

```js
Map.addLayer(
  S1_asc_logRATIO.median(),
  {bands:'logVV/VH', min:-10, max:20},
  'logratio_float'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyler, great help! I had checked the S1 data description, but I couldn't find the log scaled info. Good to receive this confirmation.